# OneDrive for Business vs Connect to Outlook

Tags: 2013, outlook, onedrive-for-business, offline-sync

Is there any documentation that explains the difference between `OneDrive for Business` and the `Connect to Outlook` in terms of offline editing?

Both seemingly provide offline synchronisation of documents - is the only difference that `OneDrive For Business` automatically syncs the documents back to SharePoint, whereas with the `Connect to Outlook` option, you have to re-open and `Update` [when you're back online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Open-edit-and-update-files-from-a-SharePoint-site-ef8dff5d-f305-4377-ad22-814ce1fda5c7)? What is the the conflict resolution process and is it the same?

Answer (score 0):

They should be the same, the changes are managed by Office clients and not OneDrive or Outlook directly.